# Best practice: git, github, lighthouse and 2 developers

Tags: git, github, lighthouse

I'm setting up a new project and plan on using git and github for sourcecontroll and hosting of repo and lighthouse for bugtracking. I've been working with git for some while now, but only been using it for more of a backup solution than collaborate coding solution.

[Edit]Reade here for more details: http://git.pastebin.com/ArzBBx6j [/Edit]

Also, I've noticed that in github you can setup a servicehook to lighthouse so that whenever you push to github it notifies lighthouse of the changes. This uses a token for user-authentication and has the ability to change tickets to resolved etc.

However, this token I believe functions that way so that whenever a user pushes to the repo (dosn't matter who), it's the owner of the repo that "updates" to lighthouse. This is a problem.

So, I believe it is necessary with 2 separate repos at github (one for each dev), and I'm wondering about the workflow that should be used.

Any1 care to shred any light on this matter? Like when to pull and push (and where), and how to make the two github repos in sync or something like that? Or another solution to the problem altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about the lighthouse part, but in my collaborations on github, we have one developer start a repository and the other forks it.  From then on, we try to keep our own 'master' branches as in sync as possible by pulling (and merging) from each other's when necessary.  A good way to do this is to make a habit (or possibly a script) of always pulling before pushing to github, to minimize the effects of conflicts.  Of course, this doesn't scale very well with the number of developers.  With more than 3 or so developers you'd probably want a single more centralized repository.